# How to save web page in one click

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, webpage, function-keys

Is there any way I can pin "save as" option on  Google Chrome, the "toolbar"

The reason why I am asking this

As you know that in a Google chrome browser, you can save any website page for later offline browsing;

Just  right click mouse and selecting "Save As' option by picking one from three different type HTML/Single/Complete
All I want to do reduce three steps into one step

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Extensions** for Chrome:

[SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle/)

SingleFile is an extension that helps you to save a complete page
(with CSS, images, fonts, frames, etc.) as a single HTML file.

[Save Page WE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof/)

Save a complete web page (as currently displayed) as a single HTML file that can be opened in any browser.

[**Bookmarklet**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-are-bookmarklets/) :
[RePack](https://gist.github.com/webdev23/0fc20feb866aaad04a515fbfae419a7c).